# R and ifelse function

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm stuck in a simple problem argument with the `ifelse` function in R. I'm a new user of R and I'm trying to fill blanks in a column ("first column") depending on values in another column ("second column").

As I try `ifelse` function, I'm getting this error `"argument "no" is missing, with no default"`

All I need is: if the test (condition) is FALSE, keep the values (from a factor variable) in the "first column" as they are.

This is an example of my data frame which has ~6000 obs

```
# 
#       first                                   second third
# 1 Cluster 1                               Chest Pain     1
# 2                           Coronary Artery Diseases     1
# 3 Cluster 6                                   Anemia     5
# 4 Cluster 7 Hypertension and Cerebrovascular Disease     4
# 5              Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease     2
# 6 Cluster 5                                 Diabetes    10
```

My try is

```
sample$first= ifelse(sample$second=="Coronary Artery Diseases","Cluster 10",sample$first)
```

The result of this is filling "Cluster 10" in first column if a have "Coronary Artery Diseases" in the second column BUT all the remaining obs in the first column I get a number. The problem is that "first" is a factor variable and I need it to be a factor.

Any suggestions?

**data**

```
sample <- structure(list(first = c("Cluster 1", "", "Cluster 6", "Cluster 7", 
"", "Cluster 5"), second = c("Chest Pain", "Coronary Artery Diseases", 
"Anemia", "Hypertension and Cerebrovascular Disease", 
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease", "Diabetes"), 
third = c("1", "1", "5", "4", "2", "10")), 
.Names = c("first", "second","third"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Can you show your code please. But should be along the lines of `ifelse( (first column is blank), (second column), (first column) )` or using subsetting `firstcolumn[ (first column is blank)] <- second column`

Comment: Thanks for your update,  For the problem in your update, you can get around the `factor` problem by using `as.character`, like: `sample$first= ifelse(sample$second=="Coronary Artery Diseases","Cluster 10",  as.character(sample$first))`. If this doesnt help. could you post your expected outcome as well please, thanks

Comment: Thanks!!! it works! BUT I have one question. If I use the as.character function it doesn't change the nature of my variable which is a factor one?

Comment: Ys, it will change it to `character`. You could wrap the `ifelse` in a `factor` call to change its class back.

Comment: I got it! Thank you again...How do I give you credit..?

Answer (score 3):

As the first column was a factor (not shown in data above), when using
`ifelse` to replace values, it coerced the other values in the column to the factor levels (removing their labels). This could be worked around by using `as.character()`

```
sample$first <-  as.factor(ifelse(sample$second=="Coronary Artery Diseases",
                                   "Cluster 10",as.character(sample$first))
```